# Stripe webhook don't work, error 500

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, stripe-payments, webhooks

Hi I setting up my webhook build with express.js in this way (the webhook is hosted on Parse.com):

```
var Stripe = require('stripe');
Stripe.initialize('sk_test_...');
...
app.post("/stripe", function(request, response) {
    console.log("Type: "+request.body.type);
    console.log("Event id: "+ request.body.id);
    // Retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON
    // Verify the event by fetching it from Stripe
    Stripe.Events.retrieve(request.body.id, function(err, event) {
        console.log("This string is not printed on the logs");
        response.send(200);
    });
});
```

Then the test request was this, generated with changing a test user subscription in the dashboard:

```
{
  "id": "evt_16oKcXAEHouDaR4rj8m5AtcC",
  "created": 1443043065,
  "livemode": false,
  "type": "customer.subscription.updated",
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "sub_71zTKb8dLfo3RX",
      ...
      "start": 1443042949
    }
  },
  "object": "event",
  "pending_webhooks": 3,
  "request": "req_72PRYW2FrgFkDr",
  "api_version": "2015-04-07"
}
```

This is my webhook log:

```
E2015-09-23T22:36:40.864Z]v342 Ran custom endpoint with:
Input: {"method":"POST","url":"/stripe","headers":{"accept":"*/*;  q=0.5, application/xml","cache-control":"no-cache","content- length":"1358","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf- 8","host":"sceglime.parseapp.com","user-agent":"Stripe/1.0  (+https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)","version":"HTTP/1.1","x-forwarded-for":"54.241.31.102, 10.252.11.20","x-forwarded-port":"80","x-forwarded-  proto":"http"}}
Result: success/error was not called
I2015-09-23T22:36:40.974Z]Type: customer.subscription.updated
I2015-09-23T22:36:40.975Z]Event id: evt_16oLqrAEHouDaR4rpAi8FWt2
E2015-09-23T22:36:43.246Z]v342 Ran custom endpoint with:
Input: {"method":"POST","url":"/stripe","headers":{"accept":"*/*;    q=0.5, application/xml","cache-control":"no-cache","content-length":"1160","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","host":"sceglime.parseapp.com","user-agent":"Stripe/1.0 (+https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)","version":"HTTP/1.1","x-forwarded-for":"54.241.34.107, 10.252.7.139","x-forwarded-port":"80","x-forwarded-proto":"http"}}
Result: success/error was not called
I2015-09-23T22:36:43.332Z]Type: invoiceitem.created
I2015-09-23T22:36:43.333Z]Event id: evt_16oLqrAEHouDaR4rcj0syMGn
```

On stripe logs I get an error "500 pending". Why the webhook don't respond correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Just a thought, for some libraries you need to call `response.end();` when you're done. Try adding that line after the `send(200)`.

Comment: Same problem, always error 500

Comment: If I don't call Stripe.Events.retrieve() the webhook respond correctly. So I think it's something with the event id and the retrieve() method that don't work. Also the "weila" string is not printed on the console.

Comment: Log the errors from your webhook server. I suspect you have some reference/api key errors.

Comment: I added the webhook logs

Comment: I don't think is a api key problem because  if I create a customer with this is working:
Stripe.Customers.create({
        description: 'Customer for test@example.com',
        email: "test@gmail.com"
    }, function(err, customer) {
        // asynchronously called
        response.send(200);
    });

Comment: I meant node server logs. I suspect your node server isn't receiving those requests or something. The log should record the request something like `9-23-2015 POST /stripe 500` if it actually received it.

Comment: Are you using Parse? You need to call response.success()

Comment: I think I don't have this type of logs. Because is an hosted webhook. Anyway it receive the request from stripe because it print the id and the type of the event

Comment: Yes I use Parse.com, I changed ti response.success() but same error and same logs. The console.log("..") on stripe.Events.retrieve() is not executed so I think that even the response.success() is not executed

Comment: Parse uses their own Stripe library that is many years old, and I'd guess that it doesn't actually support the Events API. Unfortunately they no longer have any of the documentation for any of their modules anymore.

Comment: Thanks. I try to update the library